# Integrating a function containing multiple Indicator Fuctions

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to solve the folowing integral:

$\int_0^t\frac{1}{I_{[0,0.3)}(u)+c*I_{[0.3,0.7)}(u)+2*I_{[0.7,\infty)}(u)} du$

where c is a constant, and the I functions are indicator functions. I have tried looking into how to solve this, but I haven't been able to find anything where there are multiple indicator functions involved (and I can't just break it into multiple integrals since they all fall in the denominator).

What I have worked out is that $$f(u)= \begin{cases} 
      1 & 0\leq t< 0.3 \\
      \frac{1}{c} & 0.3\leq t<0.7 \\
      \frac{1}{2} & 0.7\leq t 
   \end{cases}
$$ for any one value of t (with f(u) being the function in the integral). Now I'm just not sure how (or if) I can apply that to my integral.

Edit: Would there be a way to do this by ignoring the bounds temporarily? This integral is inside of another integral, and the only way that it makes sense is for the evalution of this integral to be in terms of t, not a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integrand is a very sophisticated way to define a certain step function $f$. This step function has jumps at $u=0.3$ and at $u=0.7$, whereas the integral is over the interval $[0,t]$, whereby $t$ can be any number $\geq0$. We therefore have to distinguish the cases $0\leq t\leq 0.3$, $\ 0.3\leq t\leq0.7$, and $t\geq0.7$.

If $0\leq t\leq0.3$ then
$$\int_0^t f(u)\>du=\int_0^t 1\>du=t\ .$$
If $0.3\leq t\leq0.7$ then
$$\int_0^tf(u)\>du=\int_0^{0.3}f(u)\>du+\int_{0.3}^tf(u)\>du=0.3+{1\over c}(t-0.3)\ .$$
If $t\geq 0.7$ then
$$\int_0^tf(u)\>du=\int_0^{0.3}f(u)\>du+\int_{0.3}^{0.7}f(u)\>du+\int_{0.7}^tf(u)\>du=0.3+{0.4\over c}+{t-0.7\over2}\ .$$

Comment: Why at each step is your final integral going all the way to t?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: As you have found, your integral is equivalent to:

$$\int_{0}^{t}f(u)\:\mathrm{d}u$$

Where $f(u)$ is the piecewise function that you have defined. Now notice that you can always split an integral, so that in general:

$$\int_{a}^{c}f(x)\:\mathrm{d}x = \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\:\mathrm{d}x + \int_{b}^{c}f(x)\:\mathrm{d}x$$

Where $a \leq b \leq c$. Now see if you can apply this to your problem, let me know if you're still having issues!

Comment: Was my figuring of the piecewise function correct? This integral is inside of another integral, so if the variables fall out I just end up integrating a bunch of constants. That seemed kind of boring, so I was afraid that I might have done that part wrong and oversimplified something

Comment: It was indeed correct! :)

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. I must have made a mistake in an earlier step setting the problem up because a value of infinity for the integral doesn't make sense in the context of the problem